# Add requirements for route with annotations

Tags: symfony

I am using the SensioFrameworkExtraBundle and trying to add a requirement for a specific parameter. I want the parameter to match a specific collection of strings.

This example from the Symfony documentation shows what I want to do. I want to do the same thing as done with culture and _format.

```
article_show:
    path:     /articles/{culture}/{year}/{title}.{_format}
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeDemoBundle:Article:show, _format: html }
    requirements:
        culture:  en|fr
        _format:  html|rss
        year:     \d+
```

This is my code:

```
 /**
  * @Route("/{type}", requirements={"type" = {html|json|xml} }, name="adm_grid")
  * @Template
 */
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You forgot the quotes around `{html|json|xml}` and you don't need the curly braces:

```
 requirements={"type" = "html|json|xml"}
```

Comment: Doing that results in this exception being thrown. ("Parameter "type" for route "adm_grid" must match "{html|json|xml}" ("html" given) to generate a corresponding URL.")

Comment: Look like you still have the brackets around the types? Paste your current annotation in full.